# Problems inserting action tokens with default wysiwyg HTML editor

Tags: civimail, tokens, wysiwyg

**CiviCRM 5.14.0**

This is a new site and I am testing inserting action tokens in emails. If I use the link symbol in the wysiwyg, it inserts double-quotes around the link but the {aciont.reply} already puts double-quotes so it gets garbled. If find if I edit the source and change it to single-quotes, it will work. However, if I toggle back to HTML and then source again, I see my single-quotes have been replaced by double-quotes.

For example:

```
<p>Hey {contact.first_name},</p>

<p>Thank you for volunteering.&nbsp;</p>

<p><strong>This works</strong>: Please reply to this email by sending mail to <a href="{action.reply}">The System Administrator</a></p>

<p><strong>This doesn&#39;t work:&nbsp;</strong>Please reply to this email by sending email to <a href="{action.reply}">The System Administrator</a></p>
```

Now, the line that says "This works" actually does work. If the recipient clicks on the link, their mail client pops up with reply filled in with the System Administrator's address.

The line that says "This doesn't work" looks exactly the same to me as the working line but it gets garbled somewhere along the way.

The email as received looks like this:

```
Sample Header for HTML formatted content.

Hey Clem,

Thank you for volunteering. 

This works: Please reply to this email by sending mail to The System Administrator

This doesn't work: Please reply to this email by sending email to ">The System Administrator
Sample Footer for HTML formatted content
Unsubscribe
PO Box 540
San Miguel, CA 93451-0540
United States
```

Notice the right caret >. This is what I mean about getting garbled. I have no idea where that is coming from. In the source both lines look the same to me.

If I can't figure this out, how could an end user possibly figure it out?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your message in a new mail as a source in the wysiwyg editor and everything seems to be fine in my installation. Are you sure you haven't made any mistake in the html?

Comment: The HTML is just as it is created by CiviCRM in Chrome. The only way I can get it to work is to place single quotes around the token

Comment: I've also tried this in Firefox. No difference